# Downloading and using ffmpeg.dll

Tags: c#, dll, ffmpeg

I have been writing simple GUIs using ffmpeg.exe.
Now I would like to try and learn to use the ffmpeg.dll instead.
1-Does anyone know a secure site to get the dll.
2-Is there any help on how to access the libraries within the dll.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the palce you downloaded *ffmpeg.exe*?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your post is off-topic for SO.